# Visual Studio Code underlines errors even though the code works with a virtualenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use virtual environments to run my code I made in visual studio code. This works just fine, but the editor still underlines the modules it can't figure out. This may not seem like a huge problem, but because it can't figure out the module, it underlines all of it's functions which is a bit annoying. Is there some way to disable underlining completely or some workaround?

[image]

You can see that OpenCV is installed on the virtualenv but it still underlines `from cv2 import *`

Comment: Are they both pointing to the same python interpreter(The virtualenv and vs code python path)?

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't know I had to change the interpreter path when using the virtual env, but it makes sense. Thanks for the help.